# Why does a fraction stored in a double become a whole number upon outputting to screen?

Tags: java, arrays, fractions

So, I have this code which is the beginning of an RSA-encrypter (current math class). Now I'm still in the beginning stages and I notice that when I try to make an array of doubles, they all come out to the screen as whole numbers, what's going on here ?

As you can see in the code I divide the multiples of 7 by 40 and it should come out as fractions (7 / 14 = 0.175 for example) but instead as 0.0.
Help

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class Encryption {

static double[] ads = new double[200];

public static void main(String args[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
        ads[i] = (7 * i) / 40;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ads.length; i++){
        System.out.println(ads[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace `40` by `40.0`. Diving an `int` by an `int` can only give you another `int`.

Comment: That's because you are dividing int by int, replace 40 by 40.0.

Comment: (Or 7 by 7.0; or `i` with `(double) i`. Anything to make at least one of the operands of the division double).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're storing an integer into the array in the first place.

Consider this line:

```
ads[i] = (7 * i) / 40;
```

In the expression on the right, you first multiply `i` by `7`, then divide it by `40`. `i` is an integer. So, let's say `i == 1`. Then, `7 * i == 7`, which is still an integer. Both `7` and `40` are integers, so when you evaluate `7 / 40`, you get *integer division*. Integer division always rounds down. When the result gets stored into `ads[i]`, it gets converted to a `double`, but by that point it's already been rounded down.

Try changing this line to the following:

```
ads[i] = (7 * i) / 40.0;
```

This works because `40.0` is a `double`, not an `int`.

In unrelated news, if you're using `double` to implement RSA, you're probably doing something wrong. Doubles aren't infinitely precise, and will screw up your result.